# blueimp / jQuery-File-Upload : Email notification on upload

Tags: jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm using [blueimp / jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/), (via [this tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/) to create a file uploaded) I would like to receive an email notification when a file has been uploaded, ideally with the file uploaded being emailed too.

[From the docs](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#done), I understand that I need to use:

```
done: function (e, data) {
    // data.result
    // data.textStatus;
    // data.jqXHR;
}
```

but.. I have no idea what to put inside here!

I'm using phpmailer.php so am trying stuff like:

```
done: function (e, data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "bin/signup_process.php",
        data: "CV Uploaded via Rough Hill",
    });
}
```

But I really have no clue how to get the uploaded file data from the script to send to phpmailer, or indeed how to even define the contents of the email.

Can anybody help me understand how I get the uploaded file data from jQuery-File-Upload and stick it in an email along with a message?

Many thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Things like emailing should probably best be done on the server side.  What are you using there?

Comment: Hi Jim, the server runs apache. I was thinking of using ajax to pass the uploaded file to the phpmailer.php script which would deal with the actual email send. Its the basic setup of the javascript that gets the file and passes it to phpmailer I don't know how to do.. (my js skills are poor!)

Comment: when you upload your file, what code is running to save the file on the server side? It is THAT code, which should be generating the email.  We can take this offline if you need more advice.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I want to do the same thing!